# react by nextjs gives error when doing npm run dev

Tags: reactjs, next.js

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpCFs.png)I have fresh install of react (npx create-next-app)
but it gives me this error...

PS C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\games> npm run start

> games@0.1.0 start
> next start

- ready started server on [::]:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
  [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\games.next\BUILD_ID'] {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\games\.next\BUILD_ID'
  }

re-download, updated node js...

Comment: Please add screenshots of your project structure and add the `package.json` as code.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to add code and data as text ([using code formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.  See [mcve] on what code is required.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 5):

I think you forgot to build the code.

You are supposed to run `npm run build` before doing `npm run start`. Because `npm run start` use the code from ".next" folder to run, not your raw code from the 'src' folder.

You might want to use "npm run dev" instead. Because it seems like you are in development phase. This will use your codes in 'src' folder to run.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpCFs.png

Comment: My bad, just saw your image.
It seems like your building was not completed.

Try closing all other tasks, and run only one task at a time, i.e.,  `npm run build`.

If the building is completed you should see the terminal and files in '.next' folder like this [link](https://imgur.com/a/QXlZEsv).

Answer (score 0):

Error is occur due to .next folder is not present in your that is related to your build folder
You need to start **npm run build** than start the server again it's getting works

Comment: You can run npm run build first. then you give the npm run start